# Some instance member can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

Earlier this week I followed some tutorial on Youtube for creating a flutter app, and I got some problems where it says that.

> Instance member 'textTheme' can't be accessed using static access.

The problems occur at LandingPage.dart

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              child: Image.asset(itemData["image"])),
          Positioned(
              top: 15,
              right: 15,
              child: BorderBox(
                width: 50,
            height: 50,
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border,color: COLOR_BLACK,
            ),
          ))
        ],
      ),
      addVerticalSpace(15),
      Row(
        children: [
          Text("${formatCurrency(itemData["amount"])}",
          style: themeData.textTheme.headline1)
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
);}
```

textTheme.headline1 was imported from constants.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
const COLOR_BLACK = Color.fromRGBO(48, 47, 48, 1.0);
const COLOR_GREY = Color.fromRGBO(141, 141, 141, 1.0);
const COLOR_WHITE = Colors.white;
const COLOR_DARK_BLUE = Color.fromRGBO(20, 25, 45, 1.0);
const TextTheme TEXT_THEME_DEFAULT = TextTheme(
  headline1: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 26),
  headline2: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 22),
  headline3: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20),
  headline4: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16),
  headline5: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14),
  headline6: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 12),
  bodyText1: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14, height: 1.5),
  bodyText2: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_GREY,  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14, height: 1.5),
  subtitle1: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_BLACK, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  subtitle2: TextStyle(
      color: COLOR_GREY,  fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)
);
const TextTheme TEXT_THEME_SMALL = TextTheme(
headline1: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 22),
headline2: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20),
headline3: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
headline4: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14),
headline5: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 12),
headline6: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 10),
bodyText1: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 12, height: 1.5),
bodyText2: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_GREY,  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 12, height: 1.5),
subtitle1: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_BLACK, fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
subtitle2: TextStyle(
    color: COLOR_GREY,  fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)
);
```

Thank You and have a good day:))

Comment: Is this your exact code and the exact error message?  Make sure that you copy and paste your code and error messages instead of retyping them.  Your error message refers to `textTheme` (with an initial lowercase `t`), but there is no such usage in your code.  Your code does have `themeData.TextTheme.headline1`.  Perhaps your actual code is `ThemeData.textTheme.headline1`?  If so, it should be `themeData.textTheme.headline1`.  Capitalization matters; names are case-sensitive.

Comment: that's not the problems, i already change the TextTheme to lowercase, and the error still the same.
i forgot to change it in here, sorry.

Comment: So can you confirm that you copied and pasted the code and error message?  What line is triggering the error?  The code you've shown does not show any attempted `static` access for `.textTheme`.  Are you absolutely certain that your code uses `themeData.textTheme` with a lowercase `t` in `themeData`?